# Xlib - Get Native Monitor Resolution

Tags: xlib

Is there a way to get the native resolution of a monitor using Xlib?

On my machine (Ubuntu 14.04), `XF86VidModeGetAllModeLines()` returns a list of display modes in descending order.  This is except for the last mode, which is 1360x768, which also happens to be the native resolution of my monitor.  Is this a coincidence, or is it specified that modes should be returned in this manner by the X Server, with the native resolution last?